# python popen rsync with rsh option

Tags: python, rsync, popen, rsh

I'm trying to execute a rsync command via subrocess & popen. Everything's ok until I don't put the rsh subcommand where things go wrong.

```
from subprocess import Popen
args = ['-avz', '--rsh="ssh -C -p 22 -i /home/bond/.ssh/test"', 'bond@localhost:/home/bond/Bureau', '/home/bond/data/user/bond/backups/']

p = Popen(['rsync'] + args, shell=False)
print p.wait()

#just printing generated command:
print ' '.join(['rsync']+args)
```

I've tried to escape the '--rsh="ssh -C -p 22 -i /home/bond/.ssh/test"' in many ways, but it seems that it's not the problem.

I'm getting the error 
    rsync: Failed to exec ssh -C -p 22 -i /home/bond/.ssh/test: No such file or directory (2)

If I copy/paste the same args that I output at the time, I'm getting a correct execution of the command.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a hint, not related to your problem: If you add some lines to your `~/.ssh/config`, namely `Host mybackup`, `Hostname localhost`, `User bond`, `Port 22` (which is redundant), `Compression yes` and `IdentityFile /home/bond/.ssh/test`, you can use `['rsync', '-avz', 'mybackup:/home/bond/Bureau', ''/home/bond/data/user/bond/backups/']`.

Comment: @mgilson Yours should rather be an answer...

Comment: @glglgl thanks for this hint. In my case I have to deal with many users/ports, that's why I prefere to use the rsh option instead.

Comment: @glglgl -- changed it to an answer.

Comment: @azerty Ah so. In this case, a dedicated interface for setting these might make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens if you use `'--rsh=ssh -C -p 22 -i /home/bond/.ssh/test'` instead (I removed the double quotes).

I suspect that this should work.  What happens when you cut/paste your line into the commandline is that your shell sees the double quotes and removes them but uses them to prevent `-C` `-p` etc. from being interpreted as separate arguments.  when you call `subprocess.Popen` with a list, you've already partitioned the arguments without the help of the shell, so you no longer need the quotes to preserve where the arguments should be split.

Comment: To expand on this, he means that don't quote the 'ssh -p 22 -i ..." part. As an example, this was the list i was passing into check_call/Popen: ["rsync", "--rsh='{}'".format(someVariable), "file" "mark@something.com:/var/www"] and it didn't work. To make it work, i removed the quotes around the {} where i was inserting the --rsh arguments. So this works:  ["rsync", "--rsh={}".format(someVariable), "file" "mark@something.com:/var/www"]

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, I googled this issue extensively.  It would seem you simply cannot pass arguments to ssh with subprocess.  Ultimately, I wrote a shell script to run the rsync command, which I could pass arguments to via subprocess.call(['rsyncscript', src, dest, sshkey]).  The shell script was: /usr/bin/rsync -az -e "ssh -i $3" $1 $2

This fixed the problem.